# How do I parse "Thu, 8 Dece 2016 09:54:00 GMT" with the extra 'e' in the month?

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am able to parse all types of dates, but this one has an extra letter in the months. How do I parse this?

I don't know how the rest of the months come but hopefully they come as months with 4 letters. I am using the format `E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z`, and the exception arises at offset 10.

Comment: Can you explain how the `e` got there? Is that a correct abbreviation of the month name when localized in some particular locale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// java    
String input = "Thu, 8 Dece 2016 09:54:00 GMT";
String p = "[^.*,\\s\\d+\\s+]+[\\s+]";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(p);
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    String month = m.group().substring(0, 3);
    input = input.replaceFirst(p, month + " ");
}
System.out.println(input); // Thu, 8 Dec 2016 09:54:00 GMT
```

If you are using the format `E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z` your date string should look like `Thu, 08 Dec 2016 19:33:26 +0000`. Not sure why the month has 4 chars. In the earlier case you can convert from one format to another using `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
try {
    String input = "Thu, 8 Dec 2016 09:54:00 GMT";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
    Date date1 = sdf1.parse(input);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    String date2 = sdf2.format(date1);
    System.out.println("Parsed : " + date2);  //Parsed : 08-12-2016 09:54:00
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Oh, missed the java tag.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the [DateFormatSymbols](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html) used by a SimpleDateFormat:

```
DateFormatSymbols symbols = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance();

String[] months = symbols.getShortMonths();
months[11] = "Dece";
symbols.setShortMonths(months);

DateFormat fmt =
    new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", symbols);

String s = "Thu, 8 Dece 2016 09:54:00 GMT";
Date date = fmt.parse(s);
```

You can also do it with the Java 8 date-time classes, though it’s a bit more verbose:

```
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
Map<Long, String> monthNames = new HashMap<>(12);
for (Month month : Month.values()) {
    long value = month.getValue();
    String name = month.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, locale);
    monthNames.put(value, name);
}

monthNames.put(12L, "Dece");

DateTimeFormatterBuilder builder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder();
builder.appendPattern("EEE, d ");
builder.appendText(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, monthNames);
builder.appendPattern(" yyyy HH:mm:ss z");

DateTimeFormatter formatter = builder.toFormatter();

String s = "Thu, 8 Dece 2016 09:54:00 GMT";
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(s, formatter);
Date date = Date.from(dateTime.toInstant());
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.